# query = SELECT id (...) returning the whole query

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm creating a script to get data from an API and save in a Postgresql database.
when I try to select an `id`, using `SELECT id FROM (...)` and save into a query, it return me the entire SELECT and not the value of the id.

```
count = ("""
        SELECT COUNT(name) 
        FROM cinema 
        WHERE name = %s;
        """,
        (cinema_name)
    )

    if count == 0:
        query = ("""
            INSERT INTO cinema
            VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s); 
            """
        )
        data = (cinema_id, cinema_name, cinema_is_active, cinema_created_at, cinema_updated_at)
        cur.execute(query, data)
        conn.commit()
        theater_cinema_id = cinema_id
        cinema_id += 1
    else:
        query = ("""
            SELECT id
            FROM cinema
            WHERE name = %s;
            """,
            (cinema_name)
        )
        cinema_id = query
        theater_cinema_id = cinema_id
    #
```

I expect the output to be the `id`, an integer number, that I'm selecting from the database. But it's returning me the whole query.

**Postgresql Log**

```
2018-12-19 19:26:14.401 UTC [75] ERROR:  column "cinema_id" is of type integer but expression is of type record at character 39
2018-12-19 19:26:14.401 UTC [75] HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
2018-12-19 19:26:14.401 UTC [75] STATEMENT:  
            INSERT INTO theater
            VALUES (5, ('
                SELECT id
                FROM cinema
                WHERE name = %s;
                ', 'Cinemark'), 'Ingresso','4');
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to query the `cinema_id` first before you actually do your insert?

Comment: you never execute the first query. what you pass to second query is just a tuple of two strings.

Comment: It's a if-else situation here.
If there isn't any cinema with the same name in db, it'll create. Else, it will select the idea from the already registered cinema and save in `cinema_id`.
Then, I'll use this `cinema_id` in another tablers as a foreign key.

Comment: I've updated the code, so the situation is better explained.

Comment: Still, you need to execute the first query to check if it will return any id(s). Not related to your question, but what if there are multiple cinemas with the same name and it return multiple ids?

Comment: You're still never executing the query in the `else` portion of your code. You set `query="""...your query string..."""` and then just print it out.

Comment: @PedroDiSanti there is no query execution in the else branch. You prepare it but do not execute

Comment: @RomanKonoval ok, so I do `cinema_id = cur.execute(query, data)`, where `data = cinema_name` and `query` is the Select(...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should search for the cinema first before you actually populate your `theater_cinema_id`.

```
# Query the cinema ID
cur.execute("""
    SELECT id 
    FROM table 
    WHERE name = %s;
    """,
    (cinema_name)
)

cinema = cur.fetchone()

# Checks if a cinema was found
if cinema:
     # Cinema exists
     theater_cinema_id = cinema[0]
else:
   # Otherwise create the cinema
   cur.execute("""
        INSERT INTO cinema
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
        """,
        (cinema_id, cinema_name, cinema_is_active, cinema_created_at, cinema_updated_at)
   )
   theater_cinema_id = cinema_id
   cinema_id += 1

# Add any additional inserts / updates then commit towards the end  
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, @fixatd .